# Checking FTP server online from Bash script?

Tags: bash, ftp

I have a bash script that uploads files to an internal FTP server. If the FTP server is offline for whatever reason , the script will fail.
How do I include a conditional in bash to check if the ftp server is up and if not, to retry in 30 minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while true; do
    if nc -z -w1 "$SERVER" 21; then
        echo "FTP is up."
        break
    else
        echo "FTP is down. Will try again."
        sleep $((30*60))
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `nmap`, e.g:

```
nmap REMOTE-IP -p FTP-PORT &> /dev/null
```

Real example:

```
nmap 192.168.56.12 -p21 &> /dev/null
```

then check `$?` if it wasn't `0` it means service is not running.

---

For retry you can use something like:

```
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ];
then 
 # do your job
else 
 echo "retry"
 sleep 1800; 
 exec bash /path/to/script.sh
fi
```

Comment: Good answer. Could you add a sleep to try again in 30 minutes?

Comment: It's Done ... ;)